# Understanding String type MAP

Tags: java, string, generics, dictionary, hashmap

Can some one explain the below code :

```
public Map<String, List<SubscriptionBean>> getSubscriptionInfo(DriverManagerDataSource ds, WebmartConfiguration webmartconnection, int publisherId, int setNo, InputDetails inputDetailsOb, ReportProperties repob, PublisherGeneralBean pubOb);
```

As i know map is pair of key and values. And in this scenario key are string type and object is List which is type of subscription bean. Please correct me if i m wrong.

Now i am unable to understand what does do getSubscriptionInfo ?

Comment: What exactly you want to understand describe something..

Comment: i simply want to know what is being passed to Map as values.

Comment: How should we know what `getSubscriptionInfo` does? We're not seeing any source code of an implementation of that method. Search one and come back :).

Comment: we can pass object as values of map. here i am just asking what is being passed here using this method in general terms?

Comment: And how should we know what this method is doing under the hood? It could insert `null`, a list of `null` or whatever `SubscriptionBean` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all probability, it builds a map. The keys are strings, the values are lists of SubscriptionBeans. After it builds that map, it returns it.

But of course, the way to know that is to read the method's documentation.

Comment: Thank you @RealSkeptic. You explain very well. I just want to know that MAP is a return type of getSubscriptionInfo.